# Symfony2 on ISPconfig Ubuntu server log in problems

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-12.04

I have a problem using Symfony2 on ISPconfig ubuntu server. Server uses multiple php versions and I use php 5.5.9 version for Symfony application. Application works fine, but when I log in, it randomly logs me out (especially when i refresh or move to another page). And also, sometimes it won't even let me log in; it redirects me back to the login page without authentication.

Thing is, the application works perfectly on a different Ubuntu server (not ispconfig). I made sure that ispconfig php.ini file and other configurations be set up correctly.

Do you have any ideas why I could be having login problems on ISPconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I managed to solve it by adding:
    post_only:  true

to my security.yml file under the firewalls section. So it looks like this now:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        provider: chain_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: example_route
            #remember_me: true
            post_only:  true
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
```

To be honest, I am not entirely sure why it worked, but I think this makes sure that login is requested only with POST method. Not to mention that I have a multi cluster setup, with different versions of php installation.